# Preallocating array for string concatenation

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

Say I have an array `x` of integers (0 or 1) and that I want to build a string `s` such that I append `A` if `x(i)=0` and `B` if `x(i)=1`, as I loop over `x`. For example I could do

```
s = '';
for i = 1:length(x)
     if x(i) == 0
          s = [s 'A'];
     elseif x(i) == 1
          s = [s 'B'];
     end
end
```

While this works, MATLAB complains about the array not being preallocated. How could I do this? I cannot for example do

```
s = zeros(1,length(x))
```

because then s is treated as a numeric array, and if, for example, I do `s(i)='A'`, I just assign to `s(i)` the char calue of 'A'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are special functions to prealocate `zeros` `ones` or similar, but you can preallocate whatever type you want using `repmat`

```
s=repmat('_',size(x))
```

Besides this, you don't need a loop at all to achieve this. The simple solution:

```
s=repmat('_',size(x));
s(x==0)='A';
s(x==1)='B';
```

As you already noticed the conversion between numbers and chars, there is also a 1-line implementation.

```
s=char(x+'A')
```